# LDAP using Spring Boot or Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap

I am currently working on a project like this. When the username and password are entered, the check will be made via LDAP and if it is correct, I need to return a successful transaction, otherwise I want a failed transaction. In short, I will log in via LDAP. We have an ldap server ready now. We have an ldap server ready now. So domain, host, and searchBase have it all. But I'm trying to understand the logic, can I do this using Spring Boot? Because in most tutorials, the name and password are entered manually. But I want the input to be entered by any client, not manually, and check if it exists on my server. If such a thing is not possible in spring boot, how can I check the username and password values sent to the method by LDAP by verifying and returning them in the code we have written below?

```
package az.expressbank.ldap.test;


/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 * 
 */


import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;

public class ControlDomainLogin {

    private String domain;
    private String ldapHost;
    private String searchBase;

    public ControlDomainLogin() {
        this.domain = "domain.com";
        this.ldapHost = "ldap://url";
        this.searchBase = "DC=something,DC=com"; // YOUR SEARCH BASE IN LDAP
    }

    Map<String, Object> amap = null;

    //  public ADAuthenticator(String domain, String host, String dn)
//  {
//    this.domain = domain;
//    this.ldapHost = host;
//    this.searchBase = dn;
//  }


    public Map<String, Object> authenticate(String user, String pass) {
        String[] returnedAtts = {"sn", "givenName", "name", "userPrincipalName", "displayName", "memberOf"};
        String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=" + user + "))";
        // Create the search controls

        SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
        searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
        // Specify the search scope

        searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapHost);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user + "@" + domain);

        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "SSL");


        LdapContext ctxGC = null;
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = null;
        Attributes attrs = null;
        SearchResult sr = null;
        NamingEnumeration<?> ne = null;
        Attribute attr = null;
        try {
            ctxGC = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
            answer = ctxGC.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
            if (answer != null) {
                while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
                    sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();
                    attrs = sr.getAttributes();
                    if (attrs != null) {
                        amap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        ne = attrs.getAll();
                        attr = (Attribute) ne.next();
                        amap.put(attr.getID(), attr.get());
                        ne.close();
                    }
                    ctxGC.close();         // Close and clean up
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Answer from domen controller is null!");
            }

        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.toString());
        } finally {
            System.out.println("");
        }
        return amap;
    }
}
```

I want me to do this by creating an API. So I will call this method in my service layer and send my username and password there. My method successfully checks the username and password sent to it. For example

@Override
public Optional login(String username, String password, String type) {

```
/*
for example when I send username and password to the following method
 */
Map<String, Object> authenticate = controlDomainLogin.authenticate(username, password);

/*
I want to match the value of method of login of parametr returned from the following method of authenticate of returned value , if they match, I want to print the correct operation, otherwise the wrong input operation.
 */
return null;
```

}

What changes can I make to my LDAP authentication method so that I can get the correct password and name values checked there?

Comment: Ditch your code. Add Spring Security, configure it for LDAP and proceed.

Comment: Why do I ditch my own code? is there any important reason?

Comment: Because you are writing your own authentication en autorization (thus security framework). Don't do that, use a proven solution.

Comment: This is our company ldap server, not my own.

Comment: Where am I suggesting to ditch your ldap server? I'm suggesting to ditch your own authentication code and use Spring Security.

Comment: I do not know How to write such a this situation in spring boot security

Comment: It is a matter of configuration of Spring Security, providing the LDAP server URL, the search filter and the mapping. Spring Security will handle everything else. See https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/ for a guide and https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/ldap.html for more information.

Comment: this tutorial doesn't helped me. because of there isn't a way, where user type from input username and password.

Comment: Yes there is, that is the default login page from Spring Security (or a custom one you provide, served by Spring Security).

Comment: but spring security of ldap doesn't give me what I want.

Comment: for example I want to that when user log in I take her name and surname which return to the response.

Comment: Yes, it does by configuring it and you might need to create your own LdapPopulator for that which retrieves the information you want. All the components are there but you might need to extend some. So yes it gives you all you need but you are focussing only on what it gives by default and not the extension hooks.

Comment: can you give a good link for it?I couldn't find it in Spring's own documentation.